# Application Insights: Analytics - how to extract string at specific position

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, ms-app-analytics

I'd like to do,

- Extracting "query" strings where param=1 as follows in "2."
- Getting pageViews in Analytics with table as "3."

#### 1. Actual urls included in pageView

- `https://example.com/dir01/?query=apple&param=1`
- `https://example.com/dir01/?query=apple&param=1`
- `https://example.com/dir01/?query=lemon+juice&param=1`
- `https://example.com/dir01/?query=lemon+juice&param=0`
- `https://example.com/dir01/?query=tasteful+grape+wine&param=1`

#### 2. Value expected to extract

- `apple`
- `lemon+juice`
- `tasteful+grape+wine`

#### 3. Expected output in AI Analytics

- Query Parameters | Count

  - apple | 2
  - lemon+juice | 1
  - tasteful+grape+wine  | 1

[image]

#### Tried to do

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#parseurl

https://aka.ms/AIAnalyticsDemo

I think `extract` or `parseurl(url)` should be useful. I tried the latter `parseurl(url)` but don't know how to extract "Query Parameters" as one column.

```
pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend parsed_url=parseurl(url)
| summarize count() by tostring(parsed_url)
| render barchart
```

- `url`

  - `http://aiconnect2.cloudapp.net/FabrikamProd/`
- `parsed_url`

  - `{"Scheme":"http","Host":"aiconnect2.cloudapp.net","Port":"","Path":"/FabrikamProd/","Username":"","Password":"","Query Parameters":{},"Fragment":""}`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, parseurl is the way to do it. It results in a dynamic value which you can use as a json.
To get the "query" value of the query parameters:

```
pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend parsed_url=parseurl(url)
| extend query = tostring(parsed_url["Query Parameters"]["query"])
```

and to summarize by the param value:

```
pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend parsed_url=parseurl(url)
| extend query = tostring(parsed_url["Query Parameters"]["query"])
| extend param = toint(parsed["Query Parameters"]["param"])
| summarize sum(param) by query
```

You can see how it works on your example values in the [demo portal](https://analytics.applicationinsights.io/demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WQywrCMBBF9%2F2KkIW0VGzdKsVf0HXpYmpHjSRpTCa%2B8ONN04W4EUEkmyF3zk04EomdQTpWsQ4onFZi6q1cOLJC77OaH4iMWxQFXkEZibNtr4pO2HJerE4e7a0CE64nBiyoas6n7B%2BERNXr%2FOjF9leu%2FIojcIQ7L%2FO9BYP5RejXu80yGYwlD4ZXQt2xEDjsgsE4BHmDwOyVx8oQUz9KTUeg5psYrIdeJLSONzWPy7zJ3upBRVxo%2BsjGzZF1Ximw4o7DlMYgY%2B1t%2FEvyBMMbOAT2AQAA&timespan=PT24H):

```
let vals = datatable(url:string)["https://example.com/dir01/?
query=apple&param=1", "https://example.com/dir01/?query=apple&param=1", 
"https://example.com/dir01/?query=lemon+juice&param=1", 
"https://example.com/dir01/?query=lemon+juice&param=0", 
"https://example.com/dir01/?query=tasteful+grape+wine&param=1"];
vals
| extend parsed = parseurl(url)
| extend query = tostring(parsed["Query Parameters"]["query"])
| extend param = toint(parsed["Query Parameters"]["param"])
| summarize sum(param) by query
```

Hope this helps,

Asaf

Comment: I could get what I'd like to do with your grateful step-by-step guide. Thank you.

Comment: This answer was specific to URLs, and while it might be helpful to some folks, it does not answer the actual question of how to extract a substring at a specific position. :( -- Not going to downvote, but perhaps the title of the question should be updated, since the OP isn't actually looking for general substring extraction.

Comment: parseurl now gets underlined in red in app insighs while parse_url doesn't. Both still work. Is one replacing the other? I found no documentation about this change.

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken hovering over the underlined element should bring up a tooltip: "The function 'parseurl' is deprecated; use 'parse_url' instead".