# How to extract specific sub directory names from URL

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Given the following request URLs:

- https://example.com/api/foos/123/bars/456
- https://example.com/api/foos/123/bars/456
- https://example.com/api/foos/123/bars/456/details
- Common structure: https://example.com/api/foos/`{foo-id}`/bars/`{bar-id}`

I wish to get separate columns for the values of `{foo-id}` and `{bar-id}`

What I tried

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| extend parsed_url=parse_url(url)
| extend path = tostring(parsed_url["Path"])
| extend: foo = "value of foo-id"
| extend: bar = "value of bar-id"
```

This gives me `/api/foos/{foo-id}/bars/{bar-id}` as a new path column.

Can I solve this question without using regular expressions?

Related, but not the same question: 
[Application Insights: Analytics - how to extract string at specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43203894/65545)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting on the '/' character will give you an array and then you can extract the elements you are looking for as long as the path stays consistent. Using `parse_url()` is optional- you could use `substring()` or just adjust the indexes you retrieve.

```
requests
| extend path = parse_url(url)
| extend elements = split(substring(path.Path, 1), "/") //gets rid of the leading slash
| extend foo=tostring(elements[2]), bar=tostring(elements[4])
| summarize count() by foo, bar
```